# putting "screen" in ~/.profile does nothing

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

I want to always use "screen" in any terminal.

i've added into my ~/.profile a new line: "screen",

just like it said here: http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3908651/Make-GNU-Screen-Your-Default-Shell.htm

but it just didn't have any effect on any new session.

i'm using backtrack 5 r3, and logging locally as root.

Comment: please read this:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55756/why-doesnt-the-screen-command-source-my-profile

hope it help

Comment: 1) Did you add `screen` or something like `/usr/local/bin/screen`?  2) if you did not use the full path to the screen binary, where do you set the path? (Before or after you try to start screen?).  3) Are you sure .profile is being used? (Add something like `echo "Yup, it is being used!"` to your .profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it to `~/.bashrc`

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

My ~/.bashrc (Add **screen** under the existing text).

```
alias l='ls -al'
alias sshvps='ssh john@vps.johnlokerse.nl'
screen
```

Source ~./bashrc by using `source ~/.bashrc` or open another terminal session.